# Hibernate does not generate tables when @GeneratedValue is set

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat

I have some code on Spring/Hibernate/Jersey. I want Hibernate to generate my tables. This is my User entity

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;
    private String email;
    private String nickname;
    private String password;
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private PersonalInfo personalInfo;
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY ,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private AccountInfo accountInfo; 

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getNickname() {
        return nickname;
    }

    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public PersonalInfo getPersonalInfo() {
        return personalInfo;
    }

    public void setPersonalInfo(PersonalInfo personalInfo) {
        this.personalInfo = personalInfo;
    }

    public AccountInfo getAccountInfo() {
        return accountInfo;
    }

    public void setAccountInfo(AccountInfo accountInfo) {
        this.accountInfo = accountInfo;
    }

    public User(){

    }
}
```

And this is my configuration:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <tx:annotation-driven/> 

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.weproj" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB" />
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="password"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.weproj.model"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

It generates the tables when the `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)` is removed but it does not when I set it.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the key column is using an autonumber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use generated value for primary key or something like that  try to use Integer in both the table structure and Java.

```
private String id;
```

try to make it

```
 private int id;
```

make sure you have designed the User table similarly(Integer and auto generated ).

Comment: Good eye!  I completely missed that.

Comment: I missed that too. Thank you very much. Marked as Accepted.